# Fazer upload de imagem para BD MySQL usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, upload

1. Meu Script PHPupload de imagem

```
<?php
// SERVIDOR ONDE AS IMAGENS ESTÃO SALVAS

$caminhonoservidor='imagens'; // este caminho será gravado na variável imagem
$caminhotemporario= isset($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'] : ''; // gravado antes de ser enviado ao servidor
$nomeimagem=isset ($_FILES['imagem']['nam']) ? ($_FILES['ímagem']['nam']): '' ; 
$caminhofinal= $caminhonoservidor.'/'.$nomeimagem; //caminho final
```

1. Funcao para Upload

```
move_uploaded_file($nomeimagem, 'imagens/'.($caminhofinal));// funcao que vai mandar imagem para o banco de dados
```

1. campos do formulaario

```
$nome=isset ($_POST['nome'])? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$preco=isset ($_POST['preco'])? $_POST['preco'] : '';
$desc=isset ($_POST['descricao']) ? $_POST['descricao'] :'';
$quant=isset ($_POST['quantidade']) ? $_POST['quantidade']:''  ;
$data=isset ($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '';
```

1. Query

```
// sql para inserir dados no Banco de dados
$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos (imagem, nome, descricao, preco, quantidade, data) values ('".$caminhofinal."','".$nome."','".$desc."',  '".$preco."', '".$quant."', '".$data."')";
// executar a query
$res = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

// testar execução da query
if ($res){
    echo 'Inserido com sucesso';}
    else {'Dados não inseridos com sucesso';}

?>
```

Comment: Qual seu script? Por que enviar a imagem para o banco de dados e não para o disco rígido? Isso pode atrapalhar o desempenho do banco de dados no futuro.

Comment: Desculpa é a 1a vez que uso o stackflow. Acho que não consegui mandar.

Comment: $caminhonoservidor='imagens'; 
$caminhotemporario= isset($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'] : '';
$nomeimagem=isset ($_FILES['imagem']['nam']) ? ($_FILES['ímagem']['nam']): '' ; 
$caminhofinal= $caminhonoservidor.'/'.$nomeimagem;  
move_uploaded_file($nomeimagem, 'imagens/'.($caminhofinal));

Comment: `$_FILES['imagem']['nam']` Tem alguns locais que o nome do index está incorreto. Verifica isso.

Comment: Obrigada vou tentar.